# TcpClient BeginConnect Returning ObjectDisposed

Tags: c#, exception, tcp, tcpclient

[image]

As you can see above, the .EndConnect() code line is returning ObjectDisposedException.

Yet why?
This is the code:

```
private TCPResult ConnectToHost(string hostname, int port) {
    IPAddress cachedDNS = DirectDNS.GetDNS(ref MainForm.DNS, hostname);
    TcpClient tcp = new TcpClient();
    try {
        #region Try connect
        IAsyncResult ar = tcp.BeginConnect(cachedDNS, port, (ari) => {
            TcpClient tcpi = (TcpClient)ari.AsyncState;
            try {
                tcpi.EndConnect(ari);
            } catch { }
            if (tcpi.Connected) {
                return; //return IAsyncResult and waitone will be true
            }
            tcpi.Close();
        }, tcp);
        #endregion
        #region If timed out, or not connected return null
        if(!ar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(_connectTimeout, false)) {
            return new TCPResult() {
                Result = null,
                Error = HttpError.ConnectToHostTimeout
            };
        }
        if (!tcp.Connected) {
            return new TCPResult() {
                Result = null,
                Error = HttpError.GeneralNotConnected
            };
        }
        #endregion
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return new TCPResult() {
            Result = null,
            Error = HttpError.ConnectToHostException,
            Information = ex.GetType().Name + " - " + ex.Message
        };
    }
    tcp.SendTimeout = _readWriteTimeout;
    tcp.ReceiveTimeout = _readWriteTimeout;
    return new TCPResult() {
        Result = tcp,
        Error = HttpError.Success
    };
}
```

What can cause that ObjectDisposed Exception as nothing here really stands out to me.

From looking at the Call Stack I can see this exception was thrown by .EndConnect's internal call to Client.EndConnect (where Client = Socket Object) and then its thrown by THAT's internal EndConnect call
[image]

Comment: It means you've already disposed the object somewhere. Do you have it in a `using` maybe? You need to show all of the code for which the `tcp` object is in scope, including its instantiation, for us to be able to tell.

Comment: @itsme86 Its as far as I can tell NOT disposed of by a call and not disposed of with a using. The entire block is pretty big, but ill edit the OP right now.

Comment: TCP is reliable so an ACK is returned when the connection completes.  The ACK is handled by the Ethernet Card.  When no ACK occurs the ethernet card closes the connection.